# ¿Un modelo puede heredar los campos de otro form en un form?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Tengo un formulario de registro, es el siguiente:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms

class UserCreationFormWithEmail(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required = True, help_text = 'Campo requerido y 254 caracteres como maximo.')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']
```

En `fields` estoy mostrando una serie de campos, entre esos se encuentra `password1` y `password2`, esos campos son del `form` `UserCreationForm` y aquí surge mi duda segun esto:

> El campo `model` muestra desde qué modelo se creará su formulario y el
>   campo `fields` muestra qué campos del modelo se mostrarán en su nuevo
>   formulario.

¿Entonces acaso al heredar `UserCreationForm`, el modelo `User` hereda sus campos? que exactamente esta pasando?

¿Por que puedo mostrar los campos de un formulario del cual no estoy especificando, si estoy indicando que me muestre los campos del modelo `User`, no de `UserCreationForm`? me debería salir error no? lo cual no da error y funciona.

***De antemano gracias por sus respuestas!***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me parece muy interesante tu duda, quizá alguien te proporcione una mejor respuesta ya que no entiendo muy bien cada pregunta que te formulas, pero creo que puedo aclararte como funciona en parte la herencia, y qué está sucediendo exactamente en tu formulario.

Como sabes, hay dos tipos de formularios en Django, están los que heredan de `forms.Form` y los que heredan de `forms.ModelForm` (hay más, pero digamos que solo son esos dos). Los formularios que tu creas a partir de `forms.Form` podemos decir que son formularios "agnósticos" esto debido a que solo son simples formularios que puedes definir y heredar y reutilizar en muchas ocasiones, un ejemplo que uso mucho es un formulario de rango de fechas, algo así:

```
class RangoFechasForm(forms.Form):
    fecha_inicial = forms.DateField()
    fecha_final = forms.DateField()

    def clean(self, validated_data):
       # validaciones
       return validated_data
```

Y esto es útil para muchos otros formularios, a mi me ha servido para hacer gran cantidad de formularios de reportes en un tiempo específico en la misma aplicación, simplemente hago así:

```
class ReporteRegistroUsuarioTiempoForm(RangoFechasForm):
   usuario = forms.CharField()

class ReporteIngresosTiempoForm(RangoFechasForm):
   ingreso = forms.DecimalField()
```

Y así, son formularios en donde **NO** debo volver a definir el campo de `fecha_inicial` ni de `fecha_final` ni sus validaciones, por lo que es re-utilizable, gracias a las clases.

Ahora, digo que esos formularios son agnósticos, porque funcionan perfectamente para todos los casos, cosa que no puede pasar específicamente con un `forms.ModelForm`. Para explicarte por qué existe `ModelForm` es básicamente porque se quería de una forma fácil poder ejercer acciones en la base de datos específicas a un modelo, guardar, editar, borrar. Debido a esto un `ModelForm` tiene métodos como `save()` el cual te permite guardar directamente al modelo definido en la clase `Meta`. Aunque un `ModelForm` siga manteniendo las características que lo hace re-utilizable (porque esto es algo del lenguaje, es decir, de Python y no de Django) su uso se hace más limitado (por cuestiones de lógica de negocio, no porque sea imposible).

Es un plus que de un `ModelForm` no tengamos que especificar el tipo de dato de cada campo, porque gracias a la ORM de Django el lo hace automáticamente por nosotros. Habiéndote explicado eso, ahora si intentaré guiarte en tus dudas.

`UserCreationForm` es un formulario similar al que te puse de ejemplo `RangoFechasForm`, por lo que al heredar de el, estás herendando sus campos. ¿Qué quiere decir eso? imagínate que por un momento estás leyendo el código de Django y llegas a [este](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L70) lugar, entonces quieres reutilizarlo, en el pasado lo que harías sería copiar y pegar, y te quedaría un código tal que así:

```
class UserCreationFormWithEmail(forms.ModelForm):
    password1 = forms.CharField(
        label=_("Password"),
        strip=False,
        widget=forms.PasswordInput,
        help_text=password_validation.password_validators_help_text_html(),
    )
    password2 = forms.CharField(
        label=_("Password confirmation"),
        widget=forms.PasswordInput,
        strip=False,
        help_text=_("Enter the same password as before, for verification."),
    )
    email = forms.EmailField(required = True, help_text = 'Campo requerido y 254 caracteres como maximo.')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']
```

Lo cual en tu caso no es nada del otro mundo, pero con formularios mucho más grande empiezas a ver la necesidad de heredar.

Entonces, espero que hayas entendido eso y como para ser más específico:

> *¿Entonces acaso al heredar UserCreationForm, el modelo User hereda sus campos? que exactamente esta pasando?*

La respuesta a la pregunta tal cual es **NO**. El modelo `User` no está siendo modificado, por lo que no hereda sus campos. Quien está heredando campos de otro formulario es tu formulario de `UserCreationFormWithEmail` el cual por ser un `ModelForm` conoce cuales son los campos de `User` (eso se define en la clase `Meta`, mira el link para más información) y adicionalmente los campos de su padre. Por lo que tendría los siguientes campos: email, password1, password2 y adicionalmente, los campos que definiste en tu modelo de `User` cuando lo creaste, pero solo vas a ver aquellos que estén dentro de `fields` en tu clase `Meta`

> *¿Por qué puedo mostrar los campos de un formulario del cual no estoy especificando, si estoy indicando que me muestre los campos del modelo User, no de UserCreationForm? me debería salir error no?*

Lo que pasa, es que si ves el código de [UserCreationForm](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L70) te darás cuenta que en su clase `Meta` define que será un formulario para el modelo de User. Es decir, cuando llames al `save` solamente va a afectar la tabla `User` y no otra. Además de eso, si esa clase no lo hiciera, tu sí lo estás haciendo, estás definiendo tu clase `Meta` y le estás diciendo `model = User`, esta es la gran cualidad diferencial de `forms.ModelForm` con respecto a `forms.Form`, por eso no te da error, porque es absolutamente válido lo que estás haciendo.

Cualquier pregunta que tengas, no dudes en comentar, y espero haberte ayudado a entender

Comment: ¿Entonces el campo `fields` no solo se limita a mostrar los campos del modelo que se especifique en el campo `model`?

Comment: Exacto, desde fields tu podrías específicar todos los campos que definas en tu modelo `User` siempre que sea un `ModelForm`, adicional, puedes especificar los campos definidos en el mismo formulario, o en el padre del formulario, es decir, si tu lo heredaras de `RangoFechasForm` también podrías añadir en fields los campos  `fecha_inicial` y `fecha_final`

Comment: Ok y, ¿El campo `email` que difini en `UserCreationFormWithEmail` sobrescribe el campo `email` del modelo `User`?

Comment: Si, cuando el campo ya existe en el modelo y tu lo vuelves a definir, entonces este es sobreescrito

Comment: Ok y una ves se envían los datos en el formulario se ejecuta todo el proceso de registro del usuario en el form `UserCreationFormWithEmail` no? y lo cual hereda todos los métodos de `UserCreationForm` para el proceso de registro no?

Comment: Claro a menos que sobreescribas los métodos y no llames en ningún momento al `super`, pero del resto funcionará igual, solo que con más campos agregados por ti

Comment: Ok muchas gracias por resolver mis dudas!! gracias...

Answer (score 2):

Lo que está pasando es simple, estás ampliando el formulario `UserCreationFormWithEmail` con los campos y validaciones del formulario `UserCreationForm`.

El modelo `User` no hereda absolutamente nada, estás trabajando con formularios, no con el modelo. El `model = User` indicado en `class Meta` únicamente indica que cuando trabajes con el formulario te va a instanciar objetos de tipo User a partir de los campos indicados en `fields`.